# Keyboard press not working with letters using pynput in Minecraft

Tags: python, linux, minecraft, pynput

I am trying to automate something in Minecraft but using pynput to press letter keys doesnt seem to register in the game. It works using a text editor and keys like Key.esc and mouse inputs work in game. I have tried running Pycharm as root, and adding a delay between press and release.

This code is a basic version of what I want to do:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as kController
import time

keyboard = kController()

time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('q')
time.sleep(0.1)
keyboard.release('q')
```

Comment: Can't edit my own post so I'll use this as an edit: I realise now I could bind the action I want to a different key that works, but this isn't the solution I want. If nothing works, I'll just use this.

Comment: You can [edit] your post. It's just that someome else proposed an edit, and you can reject it or accept it. Personnally, such as I have lot of reputation, I vote to reject it, but you can overrite my vote if you want

Comment: It says I need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits.

Comment: Oh. For me it's a bug. I suggest you to go on [meta] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and ask a question to report this bug

Answer (score 0):

There is one mistake in your code. You need a loop (while) if you want to repeat the action until exit. If this doesn't fix your problem, try to re-import the pynput in your powershell/cmd `python3 -m pip install pynput`.

Here is my code that is working if you need a reference.

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Controller as kController
import keyboard
vKeyBoard = kController()

print('Running')
while keyboard.is_pressed('p') == False:
    vKeyBoard.press("w")
    time.sleep(1)
    vKeyBoard.release("w")
    time.sleep(0.5)
print('Stopped')
```